# Linear map in analytic form from matrix form

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let's say I have the following linear map:
$$A:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2,$$
$$A(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (2x_1 + 2x_2, 2x_3)$$

And these given bases of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$:
$$F = (f_1, f_2, f_3) = \left( \begin{bmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 2\\ \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 0\\ \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0\\ 0\\ 2\\ \end{bmatrix} \right)$$
and
$$G = (g_1, g_2) = \left( \begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\\\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0\\ 1\\ \end{bmatrix} \right)$$

**First part of the question:**

Is the following reasoning for calculating the matrix for $A$ correct? Is the matrix I computed the right one? If not, why?

First of all, we calculate $F(f_1), F(f_2), F(f_3)$:
$$F(f_1) = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 4\end{bmatrix}, \space \space F(f_2) = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}, \space \space F(f_3) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 4\end{bmatrix}$$

Then we express these in base G:
$$F(f_1)_G = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}, \space \space F(f_2)_G = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -2\end{bmatrix}, \space \space F(f_3)_G = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 4\end{bmatrix}$$

And the matrix of $A$ is
$$M(A, f_i, g_j) = [F(f_1)_G, F(f_2)_G, F(f_3)_G] = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 2 & 0\\ 2 & -2 & 4\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

As a side question: is my notation correct?

**Second, and most important part of the question:**

How do you, if you are given the bases $F$ and $G$ and this matrix $M(A, f_i, g_j)$ reverse this process and get $A$'s analytic expression, the one we began with? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in the first one since the representation matrix for A is given by the values it assumes on the base, i.e.:

$$A(f_1) = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 4\end{bmatrix}, \space \space A(f_2) = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}, \space \space A(f_3) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 4\end{bmatrix}$$

And then as you correctly pointed out you need to express those vector in the base $G$
$$A(f_1)_G = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}, \space \space A(f_2)_G = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -2\end{bmatrix}, \space \space A(f_3)_G = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 4\end{bmatrix}$$

While for the second question I'm not sure I got your point, but the process is reversible, so if you have the representation matrix in one base you can switch to another base and so on...

Comment: I was wondering how you get $A$ in the form $A(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (2x_1+2x_2, 2x_3)$ if you are given the matrix $M(A, f_i, g_j) = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 2 & 0\\ 2 & -2 & 4\\ \end{bmatrix}$. Like finding the matrix from the expression, only in reverse: finding the expression from the matrix.